# How to create an even and odd list in an output txt file from aan input.txt file? in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create two different stacks from the file input.txt. I'm creating two lists `stack_odd` and `stack_even`, according to their original sequence in the file input.txt. Then I write from `stack_odd` and `stack_even` into files output_odd.txt and output_even.txt respectively. My `for` loop in `readTitles` isn't working though because everything in lines 1-10 from input.txt file gets printed into my output_even.txt list.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import sys

class MovieData(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
class Movies(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def readTitles(self):

        stack_odd = []
        stack_even = []   
        i = 0
        with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:
            for line in file:
                if (i % 2 == 0):
                stack_even.append(MovieData(line))
            else:
                stack_odd.append(MovieData(line))
            i=i+1

    def movieOutput(self, stack_even, stack_odd):
        for i in range(len(stack_even)):
            for movie in range(stack_even[i].name):
                f = open('output_even.txt', 'a')
                f.write(stack_even[i].name)
                f.close()

        for i in range(len(stack_odd)):
            for movie in range(stack_odd[i].name):
                f= open('output_odd.txt', 'a')
                f.write(stack_even[i].name)
                f.close()

    def API(self):
        titles = self.readTitles()



def main():
    obj=Movies()
    obj.API()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Is this indentation the way it looks like in your code? If it is that's pretty bad.

Comment: I don't know why it pasted like that but the indentation was originally a tab space length

Comment: Is the for loop in the function `movieOutput` that has `len(stack_odd)` in it supposed to be overwriting the odd output file every loop?

Comment: no it's supposed to add to the list D:

Comment: my for loop in readTitles isn't working because everything from lines 1-10 gets printed into my even list

Comment: Ah! I've found another mistake as well. Please look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with indentation in this particular part of your code.

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        if (i % 2 == 0): # Notice the indentation problems here.
        stack_even.append(MovieData(line))
    else:
        stack_odd.append(MovieData(line))
    i=i+1
```

Here's how it should look.

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        if (i % 2 == 0): #Ha indentation fixed!
            stack_even.append(MovieData(line))
        else: #notice the extra in
            stack_odd.append(MovieData(line))
        i=i+1
```

Your problem seems to be these two loops in the `movieOutput` method.

```
for i in range(len(stack_even)):
    for movie in range(stack_even[i].name):
        f = open('output_even.txt', 'w')
        f.write(stack_even[i].name)
        f.close()

for i in range(len(stack_odd)):
    movieTitle = stack_odd[i].name
    for movie in range(stack_odd[i].name):
        f= open('output_odd.txt', 'w')
        f.write(stack_even[i].name) # Take note here!
        f.close()
```

The fixes would look something like this.

```
#Might as well open the file here instead of opening and closing very quickly.
#Notice how the file mode has been changed from "w" to "a". "a" stands for append. 
#It will append to the file instead of overwriting.
f = open('output_even.txt', 'a')
for i in range(len(stack_even)):
    for movie in range(stack_even[i].name):
        f.write(stack_even[i].name)
f.close() #Moved outside of the loop.
f = open('output_odd.txt', 'a')
for i in range(len(stack_odd)):
    movieTitle = stack_odd[i].name #This is unused! Might as well get rid of it.
    for movie in range(stack_odd[i].name):
        f.write(stack_odd[i].name) # Fixed!
f.close()
```

Comment: Wow lol thanks for finding that! Im still having trouble with my loop in def readTitles. My entire list prints into even

Comment: @Sarah I'm going to add a fix for that in my answer.

Comment: @Sarah I've added a fix for that as well.